# Block all non-friends on facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy, profile

Is there any way to block all non-friends on facebook?

Well, I know of a profile which can't be viewed by any non-friends at all? Why is it behaving that way? Is it because it is about to deleted by facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Edit --------

Ah, ok. AFAIK, the only way to make a page show "Page not found" is to deactivate the account entirely. Check out the Help article on how to deactivate your account: https://www.facebook.com/help/359046244166395/

**Watch out** - this will remove the access to someone's profile for EVERYONE, not just non-friends. If you are looking to block ONLY non-friends, then controlling your privacy settings is a much better idea. Deactivating it will prevent the page from showing up on both friended and non-friended people.

You can deactivate/reactivate your Facebook profile whenever you like:

> I deactivated my account. How do I reactivate it?
>
> If you've deactivated your account, you can reactivate it at any time
>   simply by logging in with your login email address and password. If
>   you don't remember your password, you can reset it here. If you can't
>   remember which email address you use to log in to Facebook, click
>   here. If you have other problems logging in to your account, please
>   review the frequently asked questions listed in the Login and Password
>   section of the Help Center.
>
> Tip: If your account has been disabled for security reasons or due to
>   a violation of Facebook’s Statement of Rights and Responsibilities,
>   you may need to contact us to regain access to your account.

---

I'm not sure what you're asking here, but if it is related to Facebook's Privacy settings, you can read more about it here: https://www.facebook.com/help/privacy

Check out the "Controlling Who Can Find You" section. It provides options on turning on (or off) the ability for non-friends to find and/or message you on Facebook.

> By default, your privacy settings allow everyone to find you with
>   search and friend finder using the contact info you have provided,
>   such as your email address and phone number.
>
> If you’d like to modify who can look you up using your email address
>   or phone number: Click the account menu  at the top right of any
>   Facebook page and choose Privacy Settings Next to the How You Connect
>   heading, click Edit Settings Select your preference from the dropdown
>   menu next to Who can look you up using the email address or phone
>   number you provided?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about that. I'm talking about blocking all the non-friends, i.e if a non-friend tries to open that profile he/she sees "The page you requested was not found", just like any blocked person would see.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your comment's info.